# Django Celery Timezone misconfiguration or bug

Tags: django, timezone, celery, django-celery

I updated my Django project (from `celery==2.5.5` and `django-celery==2.5.5`) to `celery==3.0.7` and `django-celery==3.0.6`. And then strange things happend.

The first thing I noticed was that every date/time in Django Celery Admin interface was offset with 3 hours. Because my `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Sofia'` which right now is `UTC/GMT +3` hours I think that the problem is related to the timezones.

I looked celerycam logs and found this

```
UPDATE "djcelery_workerstate" SET "hostname" = 'three', "last_heartbeat" = '2012-09-18 17:57:49.000701+03:00' WHERE "djcelery_workerstate"."id" = 1 ; args=(u'three', u'2012-09-18 17:57:49.000701+03:00', 1)
```

`last_heartbeat` is incorrect it has to be `2012-09-18 14:57:49.000701+03:00` or `2012-09-18 11:57:49.000701+00:00`

Maybe some function is expecting the datetime not to be timezone aware, but the datetime passed is actually timezone aware.

My thoughts are also confirmed by an error in CeleryCam log which only happens when a task is retried! The task has this `@task(default_retry_delay = 30, max_retries = 60)` decorator.

This is the error:

```
[2012-09-18 14:46:54,001: ERROR/MainProcess] Error in timer: ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/timer2.py", line 92, in apply_entry entry()
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/timer2.py", line 48, in __call__ return self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/timer2.py", line 149, in _reschedules return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/events/snapshot.py", line 71, in capture self.state.freeze_while(self.shutter, clear_after=self.clear_after)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/events/state.py", line 225, in freeze_while return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/events/snapshot.py", line 68, in shutter self.on_shutter(self.state)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 209, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 139, in on_shutter self._autocommit(_handle_tasks)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 115, in _autocommit fun()
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 133, in _handle_tasks self.handle_task(task)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 74, in handle_task "eta": maybe_make_aware(maybe_iso8601(task.eta)),
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/utils.py", line 74, in maybe_make_aware return make_aware(value)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/utils.py", line 52, in make_aware value = timezone.make_aware(value, timezone.utc)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 269, in make_aware return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=None)
  File "/opt/pythonenv/TICKETS/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 231, in localize raise ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)')
ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)
```

After Django/Celery update I deleted all database tables and made syncdb

Timezone settings for my Django projects are:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Sofia'
USE_TZ = True
```

Django/Celery settings are:

```
# RabbitMQ Broker
BROKER_HOST                = 'localhost'
BROKER_PORT                = 5672
BROKER_VHOST               = 'tixgate'
BROKER_USER                = 'tixgate'
BROKER_PASSWORD            = '*******'

# Redis Result Backend
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND      = 'redis'
CELERY_REDIS_HOST          = 'localhost'
CELERY_REDIS_PORT          = 6379
CELERY_REDIS_DB            = 4
CELERY_REDIS_PASSWORD      = '*******'

CELERY_SEND_EVENTS         = True
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 60 * 60 * 24 # 1 day
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER        = False
```

and I don't set `CELERY_ENABLE_UTC` or `CELERY_TIMEZONE` explicitly

Edit: The problem persist with `celery==3.0.9` and `django-celery==3.0.9`

Edit: And by the way `celeryev` shows the correct datetimes (in GMT I assume)

Edit: I use PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this should be fixed in new release and as a temporary workaround branch 3.0 was suggested https://github.com/celery/django-celery/issues/183#issuecomment-10846821.

Answer (score 1):

Also this problem can be appear if you (as me) get

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

...

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

in Django `settings.py`. This 2 strings can be in different parts of this large `settings.py` config file and in this case Celery beat (for example) will show you message that timezone is changed. Something like that: `Timezone changed from 'UTC' to 'Europe/Moscow'` but real beat time that you will see will be still in UTC. To fix it, just set correct Django `TIME_ZONE` setting:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

and Celery will pick it up!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

At least according to the [release notes](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id4), the timezone bug was fixed in .0.8 and .0.9.

Use celery 3.09 and django-celery 3.0.9

Comment: The problem persist with 3.0.9 versions :(

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the release notes? There are some additional steps that need to be taken

Comment: I saw them, but they are not related, they are just fix for old records that are no longer used. I have the same problem with new started tasks